# How to rename columns using the dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several pandas DataFrame's and I want to align their column names, so that all of them have the same names of particular columns (not all columns).

In my real data sets I have many columns, but below I provide a simplified example of 3 DataFrames. All of them have the same content, but it is done to simplify the example.

```
df1 =

col1   col2    col3
111    123     abc
122    331     zzz

df2 =

colA   colB    col3
111    123     abc
122    331     zzz

df3 =

col_1   col_2    col3
111     123      abc
122     331      zzz
```

Then I have the following dictionary that specifies similar columns (in reality the dictionary is bigger):

```
col_names = {
  "col1": ["colA", "col_1"],
  "col2": ["colB", "col_2"]
}
```

It means that the columns `colA` and `col_1` should be renamed as `col1`, and the columns `colB` and `col_2` should be renamed to `col2`.

I know how to rename columns one by one in pandas DataFrame:

```
df.rename(columns={"colA": "col1"}, inplace=True)
```

However, I am confused how to use the dictionary to rename columns flexibly?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.rename(columns=dict(col_names.values()), inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1.rename(columns={col_names[key][0]: key for key in col_names}, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={col_names[key][1]: key for key in col_names}, inplace=True)
```

If the order of values in the dictionary is random and also if you are not sure about columns in data frames then you can use.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1]*3, 'col2': [2]*3, 'col3': [3]*3})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [11]*3, 'colB': [22]*3, 'col3': [33]*3})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['a']*3, 'col_2': ['b']*3, 'col3': ['c']*3})
col_names = {
  "col1": ["colA", "col_1"],
  "col2": ["colB", "col_2"]
}
cols = {}
for key,value in col_names.items():
    for v in value:
        cols[v] =  key
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:
   df.rename(columns=cols, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This approach is not flexible. I have a plenty of data frames and I do not want to go one by one through them.

Comment: @ScalaBoy This is a good answer; if you have many dataframes then you would want to rename the columns in a loop.

Comment: What the index 0 stands for in `col_names[key][0]`?

Comment: @ScalaBoy It was not clear in the question that the dataframe column names can be in random order in the the col_names. Check my new answer when the values in the col_names has mapping in random order.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.to_list()).replace({'colA':'col1'}).to_list()`

Comment: Hmm, do you propose to rename `colA` by `col1`? I have many possible combinations and I don't want to rename one by one. That's the thing.